# When Testing except after Promise I get timeout

Tags: angular

I have testing problem with jasmin and karma.

my code is:

```
  it('Should have component initialized', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) =>
    {
        return tcb
            .createAsync(MainLayout)
            .then((rootTC: ComponentFixture) => {

                mainLayout.getComponent(Component1).then((compRef)=>
                {
                    expect(compRef).toBeDefined();//this will pase
                    expect(compRef).not.toBeDefined();//this will hang and I will get timeout eventually.

                },(e)=>{
                     fail(e);
                });

            });
    }));
```

MainLayout is a Component that's why I am using TestComponentBuilder.

The problem is that when the except is matching the condition everything is OK.

When it doesn't , it's just hangs until timeout and not failing the test like expected.

Comment: It seems there is a specific problem with 'componentRef', checking the component instance not causing any problem.